# Calling new image to sprite sheet animation?

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, easeljs

I've made an animation and turned it into multiple sprite sheets, I have one sprite working flawlessly with this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ctx;
var count = 0;
var x;
var y;


var img = new Image();
img.src = "iphone.png";
img.onload = draw;

function init (){
    ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
}


function draw(){
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 204, 97);

    x = (count % 10) * 204;
    y = Math.floor(count / 10) * 97;
    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, 204, 97, 0, 0, 204, 97);
    if(count==240)
        count = 0;
    else
        count++;
}
```

What I want to do now is to call in another sprite sheet once the current sprite sheet reaches "240" where the IF statement is. In other words instead of looping the animation, call in another image and perform the same function again (with that image). I am having a nightmare trying to find the answer to this but I can't help but think it is something very very simple, am I right?

Comment: what is the function you wont to call it again "draw()" ?? and what is the different value the image ?? in this case I think you need to use a closure

Comment: Draw() is the function I want to call again yes, and I plan to create another var for the image, just like "img2".